# Copy a u128 into [u64;2]

Tags: rust, types, arbitrary-precision

How can a `u128` be converted to an array of `u64`s. While passing a `u128` to an API which takes arbitrary precision int, the API takes 3 parameters

```cpp
LLVMValueRef LLVMConstIntOfArbitraryPrecision   (
  LLVMTypeRef IntTy,
  unsigned  NumWords,
  const uint64_t Words[] 
)
```

The first two parameters are known (`IntTy` = `LLVMInt128Type`, and `NumWords` = 2). The third parameter needs an array of `uint64_t`s. The provided u128 needs to be converted to an array of u64. From the [rust doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html#method.to_ne_bytes) it seems `u128` can be converted to an array of bytes e.g.

```rust
let buff: [u8; 16] = u128_val.to_ne_bytes();
let Words: [u64; 2] = ?? // What to do here?
```

How can `buff` be converted to an array of `Words`? Also, how to deal with endianness. For simplicity, the code generator and the API will run on the machine with same endianness.

Comment: If they run on machine with the same endianness, what do you mean by "caring about endianness"?

Comment: As there are three ways to convert u128 to array of bytes (to_ne_bytes, to_le_bytes, to_be_bytes), I'd like to use native representation for simplicity sake. So we can ignore the concerns about endianness for the sake of this question.

Comment: why not just do bit operation ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just made it by hand, this avoid any unsafe and is straight forward and care about endianness:

```rust
pub fn foo(a: u128) -> [u64; 2] {
    [(a >> 64) as u64, a as u64]
}
```

This translate to:

```
playground::foo:
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    movq    %rdx, (%rdi)
    movq    %rsi, 8(%rdi)
    retq
```

Comment: For my understanding, if `let x = [(a >> 64) as u64, a as u64]`, then `x[0] = a[0:63]`, and `x[1] = a[64-127]`?

Comment: @A.K. I think that it's the opposite, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=10b437b2de1a721d9a1e0b187449484c

Comment: ah ok. so x[0] has the most significant bits, and x[1] has the LSBs. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Nothing built in in the standard library (but see [Project Safe Transmute](https://github.com/rust-lang/project-safe-transmute)). With [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck):

```
let words: [u64; 2] = bytemuck::cast(u128_val);
```

With unsafe:

```rust
let words: [u64; 2] = unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<u128, [u64; 2]>(v) };
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's safe, about alignment.

Comment: @Stargateur It is safe: transmute copies the value, so alignment doesn't matter.

Comment: as far as I know transmute do nothing, it's just compile "Reinterprets the bits of a value of one type as another type." transmute doesn't copy or anything https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html

Comment: "Because transmute is a by-value operation, alignment of the transmuted values themselves is not a concern. As with any other function, the compiler already ensures both Src and Dst are properly aligned. However, when transmuting values that point elsewhere (such as pointers, references, boxes…), the caller has to ensure proper alignment of the pointed-to values." maybe it's fine as I said I'm not very used to this part of rust

Comment: @Stargateur Yes, but we don't transmute pointers here.

Comment: yeah but I still put a my 2 cents, I wouldn't bet my life on this being safe, since at some point this could be used as a slice of ref array. I would still maintain I do not recommend this until someone prove me by a + b it's really totally safe and the recommended way to do this.